# 1 error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";"

Tags: c++

Написала код программы для этой задачи,а она выдает ошибку,подскажите что не так.И не прописала два последних условия- E-сбит ровно один истребитель,F-сбит ровно один самолет

Происходит воздушный бой между бомбардировщиком и двумя атакающими его истребителями. Стрельбу начинает бомбардировщик: он дает по каждому истребителю один выстрел и сбивает его с вероятностью р1. Если данный истребитель не сбит, то он независимо от судьбы другого стреляет по бомбардировщику и сбивает его с вероятностью р2. Определить вероятности следующих исходов боя:
 А- сбит бомбардировщик
 В- сбиты оба истребителя
 С -сбит хотя бы один истребитель
 D-сбит хотя бы один самолет
 E-сбит ровно один истребитель
 F-сбит ровно один самолет

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    float r1,r2,r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9;
    int ma=0, mb=0, mc=0, md=0, me=0, mf=0;
    double P1=0.2;
    double P2=0.3;
    int n=1000;

    //cout<<(double)(rand() % 100) / 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        r1 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
        r2 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
        //сбит бомбардировщик
        if(r1 < P1)
        {   
            r3 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
            if(r3 < (1 - P1))
            {
                r5 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
                if (r5 < P2) 
                    ma ++;
                else break;
            }
            else break;
        }
        else (r2 < P1)
        {
            r4 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
              if(r4 < (1 - P1))
              {
                  r6 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
                  if (r6 < P2) 
                      ma++;
                  else break;
              }
        }
        //сбиты оба истребителя
        if (r3 < (1 - P1) && r4 < (1 - P1))
        {
            r7 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
            if( r7 < P1)
                mb++;
        }
        //сбит хотя бы один истребитель
        else if (r3 < (1 - P1) || r4 < (1 - P1))
        {
            r8 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
            if( r8 < P1)
                mc++;
        }
        //сбит хотя бы один самолет
        else if (r5 < P1 || r6 < P1 || r3 < (1 - P1) || r4 < (1 - P1) )
        {
            r9 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;
            if( r9 < P1 || r9 < P2)
                md = ma + mc;
        }
        //сбит ровно один истребитель
        //сбит ровно один самолет
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<ma / n;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<mb / n;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<mc / n;
    cout<<endl;
cout<<md / n;
cout<<endl;
system("pause");
```

**Добавлено:**

> Ошибка 1 error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" 2
>   IntelliSense: требуется точка с запятой ";"

Где эта скобка открывается показывает ошибку `{ r4 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100; if(r4 < (1 - P1))` а где что нужно добавить, понять не могу

в 33 строчке ошибку показывает

Comment: @Маринусик, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.
@Маринусик, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Маринусик: Для начала, подскажите нам, какая ошибка и где. У нас же не «Что? Где? Когда?», тратить время на догадки нам неохота, тем более, приза не будет.
Не компилируется? Если да, какая строка и какое сообщение об ошибке? Вылетает? Если да, в какой строке, и чему равны значения переменных, упомянутых в этой строке? Выдаёт неправильный результат? Где _самая первая строка_, которая ведёт себя неправильно?

Comment: похоже просто не хватает пары закрывающих фигурных скобок.

Comment: else (r2 < P1)

else if - скорее всего

Comment: если ставлю else if(r2 < P1) то появляется окно и пишет
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'r3' is being used without being initialized.нажимаю продолжить потом выводит 4 нуля....может в коде я что то не так прописала

Comment: Не понимаю смысла в коде `(float)(rand() % 100) / 100`, почему не каноничный `rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX)`?

Comment: @VladD, видимо не для этой задачи, но разница есть. 

     (float)(rand() % 100) / 100

будет производить явно дискретные числа с шагом 0.01

Comment: @avp: угу, это да, но исходя из постановки задачи, не вижу необходимости в принудительной дискретизации.

Comment: `else if (r2 < P1)`. Куда вы этот `if` девали? Неужели для поиска элементарных опечаток надо задавать вопрос на StackOverflow? И `int main()`, а не `void main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно пишет, тк r3 инициализируется только в одной ветке.
Если из предложения else (r2 < P1) уберете выражение в скобках - оставите только else, то будет выдаваться та же ошибка - неинициализированная переменная r3.
Разберитесь, что вы написали и что это за переменные.
Не вдаваясь в замысел, мне видится так. Но правильно или нет, судить тольков вам.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)

{

r1 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;

r2 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;

r3 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;

r4 = (float)(rand() % 100) / 100;

}
```

и тд